# Why speedup reduces with increase in number of pipeline stages?

Tags: cpu-architecture, pipelining

I am watching a video tutorial on pipelining at [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_BQHUB1IsU&list=PLD8AF625E53B0691F).

At time 4:30, the instructor says that with increase in number of stages, we need to also add pipeline registers, which creates overhead, and due to this speedup cannot increase beyond an optimal value with increase in number of stages.

Can someone please elaborate this ? My doubt is that the pipeline register might be adding some delay to individual stage cycle time, so why does it become a problem when number of stages are large compared to a few ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latches themselves do have a small delay (they are after all "doing work", i.e., switching). By itself, this would only produce an asymptotic approach to a fixed peak performance value. E.g., starting from the (already unrealistically) tiny actual work time of each stage equaling the latch delay, a doubling of pipeline depth (excluding other, real-world constraints) would reduce cycle time to latch delay plus 1/2 latch delay (increasing clock speed by just over 33%) but doubling pipeline depth again would only reduce cycle time to latch delay plus 1/4 latch delay.

Even at an **infinite** number of pipeline stages with each stage (somehow) doing infinitesimal work, the minimum cycle time would equal one latch delay, doubling the clock speed relative to a pipeline depth where latch delay equals actual work time. On a slightly practical level, one transistor switch delay of real work is a relatively hard constraint.

**However**, before latch delay itself, prevents further improvement, other real-world factors limit the benefit of increased pipeline depth.

On the more physical level, excluding area and power/thermal density constraints, getting the clock signal to transition uniformly at very high precision across an entire design is *challenging* at such high clock speeds. Clock skew and jitter become more significant when there is less margin in work time to absorb variation. (This is even excluding variation in *manufacturing* or environmental conditions like temperature.)

Besides such more physical constraints, dependence constraints tend to prevent a deeper pipeline from increasing performance. While control dependencies (e.g., condition evaluation of a branch) can often be hidden by prediction, as [Gabe notes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20696042), a branch misprediction can require a pipeline flush. Even at 99% prediction accuracy and one branch every ten instructions (95% and one branch every five instructions are more likely), a thousand-stage branch resolution delay (i.e., excluding stages after branch resolution and assuming branch target is available no later than branch direction) would mean half of the performance is taken by branch mispredictions.

Instruction cache misses would also be a problem. If one had perfect control flow prediction, one could use prefetching to hide the delay. This effectively becomes a part of the branch prediction problem. Also, note that increasing cache size to reduce miss rate (or branch predictor size to reduce misprediction rate) increases access latency (pipeline stage count).

Data value dependencies are more difficult to handle. If the execution takes two cycles, then two sequential instructions with a data dependence will not be able to execute back-to-back. While value prediction could, theoretically, help in some cases, it is most helpful in relatively limited cases. It is also possible for some operations to be [width-pipelined](http://semipublic.comp-arch.net/wiki/Width-pipelined_ALUs) (e.g., add, subtract, bitwise logical operations, and left shifts). However, such tricks have limits.

Data cache misses becoming part of this data dependence issue. Data memory addresses tend to be much more difficult to predict than instruction addresses.

[This Google Scholar search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=optimum+pipeline+depth) provides some more detailed (and technical) reading on this subject.

Comment: Intel's NetBurst architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBurst) is an interesting case study on why long pipelines don't help.

Comment: @Gabe Of course, "long" is relative. MIPS R4000 was called superpipelined. NetBurst suffered from more than just very long pipelines; Willamette was innovative in several areas and (I think) suffered from a late die diet. While such is partially attributable to the deep pipeline, other factors were involved. Missing the importance of laptops did not help its reputation. Leakage power increasing did not help either. RDRAM requirements did not help early acceptance. For quick x86-64 adoption Prescott is believed to have less custom logic than earlier Intel x86. Complex failure from complexity!

Comment: That's exactly my point. The pipeline itself is fine -- but there's no way you can predict enough branches to constantly keep 31 stages full, and the leakage current made it impossible to run at the 7GHz or so necessary to really go faster than competing architectures.

Comment: @Gabe: [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) is excellent, and has some good history on why a long pipeline "speed demon" (high clock, low IPC) design turned out to be really bad at the specific time period when P4 came along, right as CPUs were hitting the "power wall" of power density being a limiting factor.  P4 was designed to eventually be good with significantly higher clocks than it ever hit in practice, like over 5GHz I think.  (And even then, the trace cache was problematic.)

Answer (score 1):

Without watching the hour-long video, I would say that the actual problem when there are a large number of stages is that pipeline stalls are worse. If you have a 14-stage pipeline and mispredict a branch, that's 14 stages that you have to fill up again before issuing another instruction.

Comment: If you can, just go through time 4:00 - 5:00 of the video, thanks

Comment: why are stalls worse? I don't understand, why can't you just clear pipeline and start over -- why do you need to fill 14 stages?

Comment: @StackExploded: That's exactly what a mispredict is.  Having to discard the in-flight instructions from all stages between fetch and the point where the mispredict was discovered (exec for conditional or indirect branches, decode for normal branches) is exactly what makes branch mispredicts more expensive on longer pipelines.  "Stall" is the wrong word to describe the case where the instructions in the pipeline are from the incorrect path of execution.

Comment: @StackExploded: However, if your long pipeline breaks up execution units (like FP add or FMA) so they have more cycles of latency before they're ready to bypass-forward to a dependent instruction, like 8 cycles (instead of the usual 4 on modern Intel), *then* the higher latency is more likely to cause stalls between dependent instructions.  You have a larger window to fill with independent work before the result is ready and you can do the next in a dependency chain.  (e.g. sum of an array, or a dot product, you need more FP accumulators to hide latency and keep more FMAs in flight.)